# Getting "Error in network definition: xxxx: No access points defined" when setting up wifi

Tags: 18.04, server, wireless

I am trying to install Ubuntu Server 18.04 and I have a catch-22 problem where I need to connect to the internet to download packages (like `network manager`) to be able to set up my Wifi

Using this [link](https://linuxconfig.org/ubuntu-20-04-connect-to-wifi-from-command-line), I am trying to modify `/etc/netplan/50-cloud-init.yaml`

`ls /sys/class/net` shows my wireless card as being `wlo1`

I am issuing the command `sudo vi /etc/netplan/50-cloud-init.yaml` and I edit the file to look like so (note,I had to visually copy this over)

```
#######
#######
#######
#######
#######
network:
    ethernets: {}
    wifis:
        wlo1:
            optional: true
        access-points:
            "****":
        Password: "******"
        Dhcp4: true
```

When I issue the command `sudo netplan apply` I get the following error

```
/etc/netplan/50-cloud-init.yaml11:21: Error in network definition: wlo1: No access points defined
                   optional:true
```

Putting aside the fact that Ubuntu Server should give a cleaner solution for this very common issue, this is really problematic because I have to be extra careful to never use tabs, to add a space after a colon and to just trust the vi indentation when I press ENTER

Can anyone tell me what I am doing wrong, what I should do to try to fix the problem, or at the very least what I should do to try to trouble shoot the problem

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create `/etc/cloud/cloud.cfg.d/99-disable-network-config.cfg`...

```
# To disable cloud-init's network configuration capabilities
#
network: {config: disabled}
```

Edit your `/etc/netplan/50-cloud-init.yaml`...

```
# This file is generated from information provided by the datasource.  Changes
# to it will not persist across an instance reboot.  To disable cloud-init's
# network configuration capabilities, write a file
# /etc/cloud/cloud.cfg.d/99-disable-network-config.cfg with the following:
# network: {config: disabled}
#
network:
  version: 2
  renderer: networkd
  wifis:
    wlo1:
      dhcp4: true
      access-points:
        "****":
          password: "******"
```

`sudo netplan --debug generate`

`sudo netplan apply`

`reboot`